# How to loop over every 2 characters in a file in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to loop over every 2 character in a file, do some tasks on them and write the result characters into another file.

So I tried to open the file and read the first two characters.Then I set the pointer on the 3rd character in the file but it gives me the following error:

```
'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

This is my code:

```
the_file = open('E:\\test.txt',"rb").read()
result = open('E:\\result.txt',"w+")

n = 0
s = 2
m = len(the_file)

while n < m :

    chars = the_file.seek(n)
    chars.read(s)

    #do something with chars

    result.write(chars)
    n =+ 1
    m =+ 2
```

I have to mention that inside `test.txt` is only integers (numbers). 
The content of `test.txt` is a series of binary data (0's and 1's) like this:

```
01001010101000001000100010001100010110100110001001011100011010000001010001001
```

Although it's not the point here, but just want to replace every 2 character with something else and write it into `result.txt` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file with the `seek` and not its contents
Use an `if` statement to break out of the loop as you do not have the length
use `n+=` **not** `n=+`
finally we `seek` +2 and read 2
Hopefully this will get you close to what you want.
Note: I changed the file names for the example

```
the_file = open('test.txt',"rb")
result = open('result.txt',"w+")

n = 0
s = 2
while True:
    the_file.seek(n)
    chars = the_file.read(2)
    if not chars:
       break
    #do something with chars
    print chars
    result.write(chars)
    n +=2
the_file.close()
```

Note that because, in this case, you are reading the file sequentially, in chunks i.e. `read(2)` rather than `read()` the `seek` is superfluous.
The `seek()` would only be required if you wished to alter the position pointer within the file, say for example you wanted to start reading at the 100th byte (`seek(99)`)

The above could be written as:

```
the_file = open('test.txt',"rb")
result = open('result.txt',"w+")
while True:
    chars = the_file.read(2)
    if not chars:
       break 
    #do something with chars
    print chars
    result.write(chars)
the_file.close()
```

Comment: This discards every other character.

Comment: OP says they want to loop over every two characters, not every other. Seemed to me like they want pairs of characters.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 See the final sentence of the question. I read that as every 2nd character. Even so its the method that is important, the number of characters is defined by `n` and the number of bytes read.

Comment: This is the correct answer...just needed to change 'the_file.read(1)' to 'the_file.read(2)'.Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to use `.seek()` method on a `string`, because you thought it was a `File` object, but the `.read()` method of files turns it into a `string`.

*Here's a general approach I might take to what you were going for:*

```
# open the file and load its contents as a string file_contents
with open('E:\\test.txt', "r") as f:
    file_contents = f.read()

# do the stuff you were doing
n = 0
s = 2
m = len(file_contents)

# initialize a result string
result = ""

# iterate over the file_contents, incrementing by 2, adding to results
for i in xrange(0, m, 2):
    result += file_contents[i]

# write to results.txt
with open ('E:\\result.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Edit: It seems like there was a change to the question. If you want to change every second character, you'll need to make some adjustments.